# Install appxupload directly into windows 10 mobile

Tags: windows-10, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I have been struggling to directly install appxupload file into windows 10 mobile using **WinAppDeployCmd**, However it doesn't work. Here is what I have been through [image: WinAppDeployCmd]

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86>WinAppDeployCmd install -file "C:\Quran_1.1.13.0_x86_x64_arm_bundle.appxupload" -ip 127.0.0.1
```

Any Idea, please?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Any error message?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the ip address of the target device. You're passing the loopback address 127.0.0.1. This will try to connect to the current local system not the target mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure that your phone is in developper mode and is "USB visible"

2) Check that winappdeploycmd sees it by using

> WinAppDeployCmd.exe devices

If you see it, you should have something like that :
Windows App Deployment Tool
Version 10.0.0.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Discovering devices...

IP Address      GUID                                    Model/Name

127.0.0.1       00000011-97e1-80d2-0000-000000000000    Lumia 640 XL ...

Done.

3) **If your phone is seen**, you can use the command you put in your question

By the way **127.0.0.1** is the correct adress and doesn't mean your system loopback in that case.